# Find and compare formatting standards

Tags: formatting, prettier

I'm looking for a web resource where you can preview what code would look like in different formatting standards so I can choose and possibly set it up in Prettier.

I recently came across this code and thought the formatting looked amazing.

```
{name: 'year',   size: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1},
{name: 'day',    size:       24 * 60 * 60 * 1},
{name: 'hour',   size:            60 * 60 * 1},
{name: 'minute', size:                 60 * 1},
{name: 'second', size:                      1}
```

I think it was formatted customly but I've seen people do this kind of alignment when assigning values to variables with different name sizes like

```
const bob   = "bob";
const alice = "alice";
```

If anyone could share some insight to the name of that I would greatly appreciate it.
And if you have any recommendations on which code formatting standard to generally follow when doing web dev feel free to share.